# How to solve for $x^{2/3}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am blanking on this, but how do I put an equation like:

$$(2/3)x^{3/2} = k^{1/2}t$$

into $x(t)$ form?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $3/2$ and raise both sides by power $2/3$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{2}{3} x^{3/2} = \sqrt{k} t \iff x(t) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{4} kt^2}$$